# Google Drive Video Downloader

Tags: video, youtube, google-drive-api

I am using [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) to get google drive video links , the problem i have it's the links i get with youtube-dl only work with my ip.

One of solution i find it's was using `https://redirector.googlevideo.com/` but it's not working for me , its give 404 error. (its work with youtube download link form youtube-dl)

There is websites using Google Drive for hosting their video and using `https://redirector.googlevideo.com/` and they dont have any problem.

I wants know should i decode signature ?

Here is google drive link example :

```
https://r1---sn-4g5e6nes.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=52840193735f664c&itag=59&source=webdrive&ttl=transient&app=texmex&ip=46.228.204.146&ipbits=8&expire=1474824502&cp=QVJMVklfU1VOQ1hNOndxcFIydWlqNFNB&sparams=requiressl%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Cttl%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Ccp&signature=9D38C83DEA269688037662F1B5795275B1E10D82.847BB187CBCDFFC5FD4582723D0CF99C97F5F19C&key=ck2&mm=30&mn=sn-4g5e6nes&ms=nxu&mt=1474809563&mv=m&nh=IgpwcjAyLmZyYTE2KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&pl=21&sc=yes
```

Comment: Would an alternative approach work for you? You can [download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) in Drive using `files.get` with `alt=media` or the `webContentLink`

Comment: @adjuremods i know i can use that method , but it's need a lot of bandwidth and beside that i want know how the hell sites like `gogoanime.ch` doing this! i am sure they use google drive for hosting videos.